# Best way to load multiple objects by ObjectId in order in a single query?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a list of ObjectIDs for some objects I want to load from MongoDB. Currently I loop through each and do a get using the Java driver, but this is very inefficient.

I tried the Morphia `Datastore.get(java.lang.Class<T> tClass, java.lang.Iterable<V> vs)` method and passed it a list of IDs. Unfortunately the order is not preserved, I guess because it's using the `$in: {...}` syntax.

Is there a way to do a single query and get the objects in an arbitrary order?

Update: to be clear, I have an ordered list of IDs and want to load the corresponding objects in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not such an option, and we don't even need such an option.

What I've done recently using Mongo is to create a `findByIds(Iterable<ObjectId> ids)` which will do mostly what Morphia seems to do, except it will return the result as a `Map<ObjectId,Model>` (or `Map<String,Model>`)

There were different possible strategies to handle ids that couldn't be found:

- Do not put the key in the map (which I choose)
- Put the key with a null value
- Raise an exception

And I iterated over the Iterable so that I'm sure it preserves the iteration order (using a `LinkedHashMap`)

You could do something similar. You have everything you need to sort the MongoDB result in your iteration order. Everything is already in memory, it doesn't cost so much...

Comment: Thanks Sebastien and David! That's a neat enough solution. I was just hoping i'd missed some neat built-in way to query by IDs in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder them after getting them from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding your question here. Is there a reason you are not doing the $in query from the driver directly with the sort option? Does the following code not work for you?

```
ArrayList ids = new ArrayList();
ids.add(new ObjectId("51e9cc5496674e6b7bcea11f"));
ids.add(new ObjectId("51e9cc5296674e6b7bcea11e"));
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("$in", ids));
BasicDBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("_id", -1);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query).sort(sort);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I want the objects in the same order that my IDs are in, which is not simply descending by ID :(

Comment: AFAIK no database guarantees ordering of results from a query without using an order by/sort. I would think your best option is to sort the in list in ascending or descending and use the same clause for the db.